# where to write logic for every widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I know this is a basic question but I wanna know how you guy's implement logic for your widgets. I normally write logic in build() function just above the return type.

Comment: Can you include some details, what are you trying to archive ?

Comment: i'm trying to solve a complex maths problem with the values given by user. i wanna know where to put that solving logic @YeasinSheikh Sheikh

Comment: you can check inline method

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by logic..?? If you are talking about like adding some values.. then we use a different method for that outside the build Method because build method will rebuild when the set state method called so some times logic can be used inside the build but some time we need to write the logic in different method and called them..

Comment: i'm trying to solve a complex maths problem with the values given by user. i wanna know where to put that solving logic @Ameer Hamza

Comment: depends on  what value user should input and waht the result will come up

Comment: you need to create a function in which the arguments will be the user input and then you can solve the problem inside the function after function completes it return the desirer result and it will create inside the class but outside the build

Answer (score 0):

Build method will rebuild every time the app state got change or refresh
if you talking about widget state
You can write it in separate file using state management approaches like (Getx,Provider)
You can write it in separate function if you need to perform setState that method will update the state
...Try to use separate functions and controllers for logic it will help you in scalability for your code

Comment: thanks, can you please suggest a tutorial on that, i'm complete beginner in this @Usama Yousaf

Comment: Sure,try this link
 for MVC pattern
 https://medium.com/flutter-community/mvc-design-pattern-in-flutter-4ad6641b7863
for Getx statemanagement in flutter
https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-flutter-getx-ecosystem-state-management-881c7235511d

Answer (score 0):

If you write your logic in build method means it will rebuild every time when the page is refreshed.
I will suggest you to follow MVVM(Model View ViewModel) architecture, so that all the business logics can be written in controllers `(ex: cart_controller.dart)` .So that your files are separated from actual widgets.

```
UI goes into - cart_page.dart,
Logic goes into - cart_controller.dart
```